# AJAX Url Post is calling a Controller that has been renamed

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm truly baffled here. I changed the name of one of my controllers.. From ArticleController to ArticlesController. I renamed the folder in the Views as well. Suddenly, the ajax query stops working. Using Chrome Developer tools, it's pointing to the old controller name. I've tried making the url a full path, but it still points to Article.

I then tried:

```
function ArticleTitleChange() {
    var title = $('#ContentArticle_ArticleTitle').val();
    var articleUrl = $('#ArticleUrl').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetFriendlyUrl", "Articles")',
        data: { 'title': title },
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //alert(data.friendlyUrl);
            var friendly = $('#ArticleUrl').val() + data.friendlyUrl;
            $('#ArticleUrl').val(friendly);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("Was unable to get url.");
        }
    });
}
```

As I thought it would be more specific, yet when I start typing it tries to reach http://localhost:50264/Article/GetContentTag.

Oh, in case you're wondering, here's the action on the ArticlesController:

I really don't know what's causing this.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetFriendlyUrl(string title)
{
    var friendly = title.URLFriendly();
    return Json(new { friendlyUrl = friendly });
}
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? I'm really baffled.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean? I changed the url above from "GetFriendlyUrl" to the url shown above. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed something in the Kendo().Autocomplete. It has it's own transport method, which was pointing to Article. Doh! Thanks for all the help